# System proxy not working under windows proxy with cntlm on linux

Tags: linux, proxy, cntlm

As per title I'm trying to set my pc where I have Neon 5.27 release 22.04 under  proxy. I've been given permission to access the the network but none is willing to help.

So after researching I configured cntlm and set apt.config to use cntlm as proxy at localhost:3128.

Since I would like to be able to switch to no proxy when I'm not using the company connection, I'm trying to set the system proxy variable so that other program can use those info.\

Thus I modified /etc/environment file adding cntlm as proxy by doing for example

```
export http_proxy=localhost:3128
```

and so on for http and ftp as suggested https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-setup-apt-proxy-on-ubuntu/

The problem is that when I tell firefox or telegram to use system proxy settings, they are not able to connect unlike apt.

What am I doing wrong?